# The proper way to work with multiple pages each page has a listview

Tags: java, android

my app will have 3 pages the first page will have 12 button in each button click there is an array that will be listed in the second page and each item/cell of this listview will have a another array that will be listed in page 3 in a listview as well what is the proper way to do this without making a separate activity for each button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewPager to create fragments in each page.

```
class ViewPager(fm: FragmentManager): ViewPagerAdapter(fm){

    override fun getPosition(position: Int): Fragment?{
        return when(position){
            0 -> Fragment1.newInstance();
            1 -> Fragment2.newInstance();
            2 -> Fragment3.newInstance();
            else -> throw Exception()
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int{
        return 3
    }
}
```

Then your first fragment has those 12 buttons. Second fragment has ListView. Your third fragment will have Listview too.

Comment: I thing you misunderstood the question. He said First Page will have 12 buttons --> click on any button --> open new page having a list --> click any item --> open new page having a list. (All lists are dependent on previous click, they mapped to a previous item.)

Comment: @beginner Exactly that what I'm looking to do

Comment: @OmarBaq you can use fragments. create a new fragment on button click and add it to the backstack, do not use replace, so if you press back you will land on previous fragment/page. this can be done using a single activity and a container for holding fragments.